# How can I get valid from and valid till from a certificate in python

Tags: python, certificate, m2crypto

I am trying to get the certificate valid from and valid till using Python. Is there any way to get these information using M2Crypto in Python?

Comment: Tried anything? Or googled and found stuff like [this](https://gist.github.com/bretwalker/5420652)?

Comment: Actually I have one certificate file with .crt extensions.  If i pass the certificate file to a method, then it should return valid from and valid to from the certificate file. Things which you mentioned is based on the hostname.

Answer (score 0):

We have to use the following code to get the valid From and valid to from the certificate file using M2Crypto.

```
m2cert = M2Crypto.X509.load_cert_string(cert)
validTo = m2cert.get_not_after()
validFrom = m2cert.get_not_before()
```